# Projeto de algoritmos por divisão e conquista

Tags: array, algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Preciso projetar esse algoritmo utilizando o paradigma de divisão e conquista (indução forte). Não estou conseguindo sair do lugar...

> Sejam A e B dois vetores de números inteiros tais que o número total de inteiros nos dois vetores é `n`, e `x` um número inteiro. Projete um algoritmo de complexidade *O(n log n)* para o problema de determinar se existem índices i e j tais que `A[i] + B[j] = x`".

Comment: É interessante mencionar que esse problema pode ser resolvido em O(n) com hashtables. Esse é basicamente o clássico [*Two Sum*](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/) mas com a pequena variante de ser com 2 arrays em vez de 1,

Answer (score 2):

O algoritmo seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
função z(int[n] A, int[n] B, int x) {     // Linha 1
    C = copy(B)                           // Linha 2
    sort(C)                               // Linha 3
    int i, k = -1                         // Linha 4
    for (i = 0; i < n && k == -1; i++) {  // Linha 5
        k = binary_search(C, x - A[i])    // Linha 6
    }                                     // Linha 7
    if (k == -1) return [-1, -1]          // Linha 8
    j = indexof(B, C[k])                  // Linha 9
    return [i, j]                         // Linha 10
}                                         // Linha 11
```

Nesse algoritmo:

- `copy` é a função que cria uma cópia de um array.
- `sort` é a função que ordena um array.
- `binary_search` é a função que procura por um elemento em um array ordenado usando a busca binária e retorna a posição onde o elemento é encontrado. -1 é retornado se o elemento não for encontrado.
- `indexof` é a função que retorna em qual posição de um array (possivelmente desordenado) um determinado elemento se encontra.

A função retorna um par de elementos que correspondem às posições `[i, j]` dos elementos procurados. Caso não existam `i` e `j` tais que `A[i] + B[j] = x`, então `[-1, -1]` é retornado.

A ideia é você criar uma cópia ordenada de B chamada C. Com isso, você pode percorrer cada posição de A usando `i` como contador e procurando por meio de busca binária o elemento correspondente em C em uma posição `k`. Se a busca em C nunca for bem sucedida após todo o array A ter sido percorrido, então `[-1, -1]` é retornado. Senão, quando a busca binária for bem sucedida, o valor correto de `i` é determinado e então basta procurar em `B` o elemento em `C[k]` para descobrir o valor de `j`.

- A complexidade da linha 2 é *O(n)*.
- A complexidade da linha 3 é *O(n log n)*. Para tal, basta usar um algoritmo tal como o mergesort como implementação de `sort`.
- O laço das linhas 5-7 é executado no pior caso *O(n)* vezes.
- Cada iteração da linha 6 tem uma complexidade de *O(log n)*.
- Logo, a complexidade total do laço das linhas 5-7 é *O(n log n)*.
- A linha 9 tem complexidade *O(n)* no pior caso. Uma busca sequencial em B é suficiente.
- As linhas 4, 8 e 10 tem complexidade *O(1)*.

Logo, a complexidade total é *O(n) + O(n log n) + O(1) + O(n log n) + O(1) + O(n) + O(1)* e isso é *O(n log n)*.

Há um porém apenas. Isso não é um algoritmo de divisão-e-conquista. No entanto, isso talvez venha a te servir ao menos como base para produzir um que seja.